# Where to close opened clients or use java garbage collection in JSF?

Tags: jsf, elasticsearch, liferay, portlet

I use JSF portlets with Liferay. In the bean's constructer, I created some objects and also some clients  to access some servers. I don't know where should I deconstruct those objects or use garbage collector and also close those clients when I refreshed the page or redirected any other page.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the constructor. For sure not if you're using CDI. Also for sure don't rely on GC when it comes to cleaning up expensive resources. Just use [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) annotations on the desired methods. The bean management framework will all by itself explicitly call them when the bean scope starts and ends.

```
public class Bean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

This works on both JSF and CDI managed beans. Only when using `@ViewScoped` in JSF 2.0-2.1, the `@PreDestroy` isn't guaranteed to be invoked in all circumstances. In case you're using CDI on a Servlet (i.e. non-Portlet) environment, the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`@ViewScoped`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/ViewScoped) solves this problem of JSF 2.0-2.1 `@ViewScoped` `@PreDestroy` fail.